# Wrong element is removed from array

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [this](https://github.com/tajo/react-movable) library for one of our React projects, it works fine, but there is a bug with it.

I have a `SidebarSizeModal` React component, which acts like a modal to add/edit/remove and move the sizes (like S, M, L, XL). I have `data.sizes` array in my ContextAPI. So, in this component, I have:

```
  const data = useData();
  const [tempSize, setTempSize] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

and I'm just initiating this `tempSize` array

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTempSize(data.sizes);
  }, [data.sizes]);
```

The issue happens when I try to remove the size, which I do with `id`.

```
  const onRemoveMeasurement = async (title, id) => {
    if (title === "M") {
      // If it's "M", you may want to handle this differently
      console.log("You can't remove the 'M' size.");
    } else {
      // Filter out the size to remove from tempSize
      const updatedTempSize = tempSize.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
      setTempSize(updatedTempSize);

      // Update the data.sizes and perform any other required actions
      const updatedDataSizes = data.sizes.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
      data.setSizes(updatedDataSizes);
    }
  };
```

Here, if I try to remove S, L is getting removed and etc.

My `List` is like following:

```
<List
              values={tempSize}
              onChange={({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
                setTempSize([]);
                setTimeout(() => {
                  setTempSize(arrayMove(tempSize, oldIndex, newIndex));
                }, 1);
              }}
              renderList={({ children, props }) => <ul {...props}>{children}</ul>}
              renderItem={({ value, index, props }) => (
                <li {...props}>
                 <input
                    type="text"
                    defaultValue={!value.title ? value.size : value.title}
                    disabled={value.title === "M" || value.size === "M"}
                    onKeyUp={(e) => onChangeName(value.id, e.target.value)}
                  />
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className={styles.remove_btn}
                    onClick={() => onRemoveMeasurement(value.title, value.id)}
                  ></button>
                </li>
              )}
            />
```

I debugged a bit the `onRemoveMeasurement` code, which gives following results:

```js
      console.log(tempSize); // gives S, M, L, XL
      const updatedTempSize = tempSize.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
      setTempSize(updatedTempSize);
      console.log(updatedTempSize); // gives M, L, XL
```

the result is correct, but on the page, it shows `S, M, L`, where it shows `XL` is removed instead of `S` and `S` gets disabled for some reason.

I added [this CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-wiles-fghpmx?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Can you create a codesanbox example ?

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei I would try to create one with dummy data. Let me see if I can install this library there.

Comment: You need to give each list item a unique `key` prop. Can't use index, or not provide a key at all (cos in that case I think React uses index by default). The problem you're experiencing is classic example of this. Something like `<li key={value} {...props}>` if the values are unique

Comment: I have added link. @Jayce444, I have tried it, but it does not work either. You may check CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue after @Jayce444 mentioned the `key` issue. It does not have any effect if I put it in `li` tag, but it works good if it is in `input` tag.

```
 <input
       key={value.id} // added key to input tag
       type="text"
       defaultValue={!value.title ? value.size : value.title}
       disabled={value.title === "M" || value.size === "M"}
       onKeyUp={(e) => onChangeName(value.id, e.target.value)}
 />
```

Comment: Or you could change 'defaultValue' to 'value'.

Comment: Indeed yes, @Ergis. Completely forgot about that.